# How to test for nth-child using Modernizr?

Tags: css, css-selectors, modernizr

I'm trying to use modernizr to test for `:nth-child` browser support but I'm not sure how to do it, I found this one http://jsfiddle.net/laustdeleuran/3rEVe/ which tests for `:last-child` but I don't know how to change it to detect `:nth-child` (I was also thinking about using it like that since I believe that browsers that don't support `:last-child` don't support `:nth-child` either but I'm not sure)

Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest, it's very reasonable to assume that a browser either supports both `:nth-child()` and `:last-child`, or does not support either.

Comment: Try this plugin.. http://selectivizr.com/ <br>
insert under/after css file only!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just wrote a function to detect the :nth-child support for you

```
function isNthChildSupported(){
var result = false,
    test =  document.createElement('ul'),
    style = document.createElement('style');
test.setAttribute('id', 'nth-child-test');
style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
style.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
style.setAttribute('id', 'nth-child-test-style');
style.innerHTML = "#nth-child-test li:nth-child(even){height:10px;}";
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    test.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));   
}
document.body.appendChild(test);
document.head.appendChild(style);
  if(document.getElementById('nth-child-test').getElementsByTagName('li')[1].offsetHeight == 10) {result = true;}
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('nth-child-test'));
document.head.removeChild(document.getElementById('nth-child-test-style'));
  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
isNthChildSupported() ? console.log('yes nth child is supported') : console.log('no nth child is NOT supported');
```

You can see this works in action here
http://jsbin.com/epuxus/15

Also There is a difference between [jQuery `:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [CSS `:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-child).

jQuery `:nth-child` **is** supported in any browser jQuery supports but CSS `:nth-child` [is supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) in IE9, Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does work but after looking around a bit more I found this https://gist.github.com/441842 which actually tests for all selectors, hopefully someone will find it useful too.

Comment: I know this is older, but does anyone else receive an error in IE8 when using this function? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631871/modifying-the-innerhtml-of-a-style-element-in-ie8

Answer (score 3):

I remember there was a Modernizr selectors plugin that tested for selectors support, but I can't find it right now. You can take a look at this: http://javascript.nwbox.com/CSSSupport/ which is similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to add CSS3 selector support to unsupported browsers

Answer (score 1):

Mohsen, thank you for your decision. 
If someone needs to jQuery:

```
function test(){

  var result = false,
      test =  $('<ul id="nth-child-test"><li/><li/><li/></ul>').appendTo($('body')),
      style = $('<style type="text/css">#nth-child-test li:nth-child(even){height:10px;}</style>').appendTo($('head'));

  if(test.children('li').eq(1).height() == 10)
    result = true;

  test.remove();
  style.remove();

  return result;

};
```